# Python and MySQL - Weak Reference Error when Executing Query

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

I am new to Python and MySQL and having some trouble with a connection class that I am using to execute queries.

Here is my what I have so far:

```
class DbConnection:

    def __init__(self):
            db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=cfg.mysql["host"], 
            user=cfg.mysql["user"], 
            passwd=cfg.mysql["passwd"], 
            database=cfg.mysql["database"]
            )
            self.cursor = db.cursor()
            
    def query(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
    
test = DbConnection()



test.query('SELECT * FROM DaycareDogs')
```

When I try and run this (or any query) I am getting "ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists".

I am very new to coding and this is my first real project so am learning on the fly.

Is there something I am missing? I have seen a few other similar problems and did what was recommended but still no luck.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the database connection a property of the class, by also adding self in front of it

```
class DbConnection:

def __init__(self):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=cfg.mysql["host"], 
        user=cfg.mysql["user"], 
        passwd=cfg.mysql["passwd"], 
        database=cfg.mysql["database"]
        )
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        
def query(self, sql):
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
    return self.cursor.fetchall()

test = DbConnection()

test.query('SELECT * FROM DaycareDogs')
```

Since the variable db is in the local scope, when the 'init' constructor ends, the variable will be destroyed, therefore the connection

Comment: That seemed to get me past the error I was having! For some reason the results are not displaying as I had thought. Is that not what the return self.cursor.fetchall() is for?

Comment: I did modify the Query function a bit to:

def query(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        for x in self.cursor:
            print(x)

That allowed me to see the results. Is there a better way? But your original solution allowed me to correct the issue!

Comment: @placebo398 `return` *returns* a value from a function to the calling code. You probably want to assign it to a variable to do something with it, e.g. `result = test.query('Select [...]);  print(result)`